# Identifying the quotient of lie algebras $\mathfrak{g}/ \mathfrak{g}_r$

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let G be a compact connected with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$. Let $r \in \mathfrak{g}$, we denote by $\mathfrak{g}_r$ the Lie algebra of the stabilizer subgroup $G_r$ under the adjoint action.

Why is  $[\mathfrak{g},r]$ isomorphic to $\mathfrak{g}/ \mathfrak{g}_r$ ?

Ps: I don't have a reference for this result ( it's just a friend of mine who told me that he'd come across it without knowing the proof!).

Comment: There is a relatively obvious linear surjection $\mathfrak g \rightarrow [\mathfrak g, r]$ whose kernel is the centraliser of $r$, which unless I'm very off is $\mathfrak g_r$. Note that neither side of this identification is a Lie algebra in general, so we just have an iso of vector spaces.

Comment: Thank you @Torsen for your comment! I have just some doubt about the requirement that G is connected, is it necessar or no ?

Comment: Actually, I should point out that the notation used here and in my above comment is not common: Often $[L, M]$ for subalgebras $L, M$ means the *subalgebra generated by all commutators* $[l,m]$. For what I said above to hold true, I assumed by $[\mathfrak g, r]$ you meant just the vector space generated by all $[g, r]$, which in this case indeed is just the set of all $[g,r]: g \in \mathfrak g$. For the more common meaning, the map I meant above is not surjective, and the iso is not true for dimension reasons in general.